# twilio conference call gathering digits feature missing

Tags: twilio, conference

I'm currently working on an automated voice call interpreter. I know that it's not currently possible to gather digits during a conference call directly. That's why I had to come up with a workaround and let twilio dial into the conference call, so that I can gather the participants digits. It works great but the problem is that it's costing me around 4.2c per minute, which of course is not ideal at all.

Is this feature currently on your to do list and if yes, when are you going to make it publicly available?

Cheers,
Marcel

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Depending on what you want to do this technique might get you better results.  It leverages the hanguponstar attribute of the `<Dial>` verb:

[Twilio call transfer from in-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581902/twilio-call-transfer-from-in-call)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't help me because I want to be able to track all digits.

So once again, is this feature on your feature list or not? If not I would like to ask you if you could add it. I've seen some previous posts from other users, so this problem / missing feature has been known for more than over a year.

Cheers