# how to handle call transfer with twilio?

Tags: twilio, phone-call

I'am using twilio to set up a call between 2 people 
I'd like to manage call transfer asked from one side (like when a dtmf key is pressed). The other side could listen to a prompt who could be "please wait while your call is being transfered"

Any chance to do that properly with twilio?

Answer (score 0):

When both parties are connected, Twilio blocks execution of further verbs until the caller or called party hangs up. That's why it is not possible in regular way.

But you can hangupOnStar attribute to hangup the caller party. And set an action URL to continue next dial verbs.

Here is a detail answer:
[Twilio call transfer from in-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581902/twilio-call-transfer-from-in-call)